# Entity Framework generated queries for nested collections

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate, orm

Using Entity Framework 6.

Suppose I have an entity `Parent` with two nested collections `ICollection<Child>` and `ICollection<Child2>`.  I want to fetch both eagerly:

`dbContext.Parent.Include(p => p.Child).Include(p => Child2).ToList()`

This generates a big query, which looks like this at a high level:

```
SELECT ... FROM (
   SELECT (parent columns), (child columns), NULL as (child2 columns)
   FROM Parent left join Child on ... 
   WHERE (filter on Parent)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (parent columns), NULL as (child columns), (child2 columns)
   FROM Parent left join Child2 on ...  
   WHERE (filter on Parent)
))
```

Is there a way to get Entity Framework to behave like batch fetch in NHibernate (or JPA, EclipseLink, Hibernate etc.) where you can specify that you want to query the parent table first, then each child table separately?

```
 SELECT ... from Parent -- as usual
 SELECT ... from Child where parent_id in (list of IDs)
 SELECT ... from Child2 where parent_id in (list of IDs)
 -- alternatively, you can specify EXISTS instead of IN LIST:
 SELECT ... from Child where exists (select 1 from Parent where child.parent_id = parent.id  and (where clause for parent))
```

I find this easier to understand and reason about, since it more closely resembles the SQL you would write if you were writing it by hand.  Also, it prevents the redundant parent table rows in the result set.  On the other hand, it's more round trips.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible with the Entity Framework, at least using LINQ. At the end of the day the ORM attempts to generate the most efficient query possible, at least to it. That being said ORMs like Entity don't always generate the nicest looking SQL or the most efficient. My guess, and this is just a guess, is Entity is trying to reduce the number of trips and I/O becaus I/O is experience, in relativity.

If you are looking for fine grain control over your SQL I recommend you avoid ORMs, or do like I do, use Entity for your basic CRUD and simple queries, used stored procedures for your complex queries, such as complex reports. There is always the ADO.NET too, but seems like you are more intent on using an ORM.

You may fine this useful as well. Basically not much tuning is available. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390400/2272004

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework misses out on many sophisticated features NHibernate offers. EF's unique selling point is its versatile LINQ support, but if you need declarative control over how an ORM fetches your data spanning multiple tables, EF is not the tool of choice. With EF, you can only try to find procedural tricks.

Let me illustrate that by showing what you'd need to do to achieve "batch fetching" with EF:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
context.Children1.Where(c1 => parentIds.Contains(c1.ParentId)).Load();
context.Children2.Where(c2 => parentIds.Contains(c2.ParentId)).Load();
var parents = dbContext.Parent.Where(p => parentIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

This loads the required data into to context and EF connects the parent and children by *relationship fixup*. The result is a `parents` list with their two child collections populated. But of course, it has several downsides:

- You need disable lazy loading, because even though the child collections are populated, they are not marked as loaded. Accessing them would still trigger lazy loading, when enabled.
- Repetitive code: you need to repeat the predicates three times. It's not really easy to avoid this.
- Too specific. For each different scenario, even if they are almost identical, you have to write a new set of statements. Or make it configurable, which is still a procedural solution.
- EF's current main production version (6) doesn't have a query batch facility. You need third-party tools like EntityFramework.Extended to run these queries in one database roundtrip.