# Entity Framework Core Query Generation

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, query-optimization

Related Topic: [Entity framework performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389444/entity-framework-performance-tuning)

Does `Entity Framework Core` always generate query with best performance? Does any body have a **Counter-Example** (EF query has less performance vs raw SQL query (EF generate a SQL query that we can write it in better way using raw SQL))?

Thanks

Comment: Simple one: Group by key and get first element of the group. SQL will be effective. Actually I can provide more examples, but their size will be like a big Blog post.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks. Could you please give one example of `Group` by key?

Comment: `var result = context.OrderDetails.GroupBy(x => x.OrderId).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.CreateDate).First())` - gat last order detail. Note that this will work only with EF Core 6 +

Comment: Then EF still has Parameter Sniffing problem, but I think it can be solved with interceptors at least for SQL Server.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. It invites potentially hundreds of people to post generated queries that perform bad. It'll be impossible to nominate one single correct answer, which a SO question should aim at.

Comment: @GertArnold, No No... Please consider I want afew example that developers faced with. I mean we shouldn't consider EF as **best** tools to querying data. For example we know that EF has very bad performance in batch scenario. But I want to see some simple example (like what SvyatoslavDanyliv said)...

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I know parameter sniffing problem but I mean just compare EF generated query and Raw SQL query that does same query in better way

Comment: You can't (and won't) stop people from posting answers for years to come. It happens all the time on questions like this when they don't get closed in time.

Comment: @GertArnold Please remove you close vote...please help us to clarify this issue. Yes but posting answer to this topic may lead to better decision developer can made... . I think that is not bad thing.

Comment: @Arian, better tell me why you need such comparison? EF Core is full bloated ORM and its LINQ translator is not full SQL replacement. But usually it good enough in 99%

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I want that 1%. Simple queries that can write with SQL in better way

Comment: Well, it is a big topic. And I agree with @GertArnold that this not suitable with SO. Ask same question in a flame ready `reddit.com/r/dotnet` and you will be surprised with answers, and probably my answers also.

Comment: This forum is littered with questions like "how to I speed up this query in this framework.  Sometimes an `INDEX` is the solution, but many times a raw query is needed.  Search by tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, one case maybe really stands out. It is that EF always generates outer joins when `Include()`-ing a collection. If we have prior knowledge that parents without children don't exist (or we don't need them) there's no way to instruct EF to generate an inner join for the `Include`, while there may be considerable performance differences between outer (worst) and inner joins (best).

To me, this was annoying enough to make me [coin an `IncludeInner`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24955) method, which was rejected, unfortunately (and, fair enough, I didn't submit a pull request).

From an EF perspective it makes sense to generate outer joins. After all, a query like...

```cs
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children)
```

...is expected to return *all* parents, not only the ones with children.

So now if we're interested in only parents with children we have to revert to a query like:

```cs
context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children)
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any()
```

We now have an `OUTER JOIN` *and* an `EXISTS` predicate that both access the Children table. If performance is really critical we can't but write SQL with an inner join ourselves, or write LINQ with a join statement, not using navigation proeprties.

In EF's defense, it should be noted that query generation in general has improved immensely in EF-core, as compared to its early versions and esp. Entity Framework 6 (for .net framework). While EF6 was lamentable, I dare say that EF-core-6 is one of the best now. (Although `GroupBy` support remains an issue).

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. That's what I need. You're the ONE. Can you explain a bit about `GROUP BY` problem? Thanks

Comment: In short, GroupBy is supported as far as it looks like SQL, i.e. returning groups of entire entities isn't supported, as EF6 did. EF-core-6 [improved slightly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#improved-groupby-support).

Answer (score 0):

There are many performance tips for Efficient Querying like Tracking, no-tracking and identity resolution, split queries , indexes ,
EF is ORM (object relational mapping) that finally translated to end Db Engine
To prevent the programmer from getting involved in the database language
has its own overhead cost
you can also use raw SQL queries with
`FromSqlRaw`

you can learn more

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **No**,

**Explanation**

EFCore (short for Entity Framework Core) does not aim to generate query with better performance, EFCore only aims to generate query based on the model you have provided. EFCore will create correct query based on the result you are trying to achieve.

Queries are only generated based on the navigation properties and foreign keys involved.

Databases mostly use index statistics to generate best query plans, that has nothing to do with if query is written using EFCore or plain SQL.

Irrespective of the way you write queries using EFCore, SQL server will choose most efficient plan always.

**Split Queries**

EFCore provides query splitting, which results in smaller datasets compared to many number of joins in single query generated by older Entity Framework.

You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries, it definitely is faster compared to earlier Entity Framework.

We have seen query times dropping to 20ms from 2 seconds, using split queries. There are very small inconsistencies as both occur in different time, and are actually executed as many separate queries. But for most part, it is sufficient and fast. And best part is you can use `.AsSingleQuery()` to use single query.